# Why are fine structure energies $ \propto \alpha^4 $?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, atomic-physics, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

There are 3 main contributions to the fine structure energy shifts: relativistic kinetic energy, LS (spin-orbit) coupling and the Darwin term. All these shifts to lowest order scale as $\alpha^4$ where $\alpha$ here is the fine structure constant. Is there an easy way to see why this is?

Comment: Note their was originally an error in this post. I asked why it was $\propto \alpha^2$ where I it is infact $\propto \alpha^4$. This has now been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to look how the relativistic energy scales.

In the Bohr model the fine structure energy is related to the (ground state) velocity by:
$$\alpha=\frac{v}{c}$$
In relativity the energy is of a particle is given by:
$$E=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
Expanding this in terms of $v/c$ we get:
$$ E= mc^2 \left( 1+\frac{v^2}{2c^2}+\frac{3v^4}{8c^4}+...\right)$$
The first term here is the rest energy, the second is the classical energy which since is proportional to $v^2$ we would expect the gross energy of the atom $\propto \alpha^2$. Higher order terms are related to relativistic corrections, the most prominent one been $\frac{v^4}{c^4 }$ and thus we expect the relativistic corrections to be of the order of $\alpha^4$.